# Use the symbol for partial derivative \partial in mathabx

Tags: math-mode, packages, mathabx

I am currently using the `mathabx` package, which redefines a lot of the standard symbols. I actually like most of the differences with the exception of the partial derivative symbol. Would it be possible to redefine the partial derivative command so that when I type `\partial`, we get the standard partial derivative symbol?

Below are the partial derivative symbols (`mathabx` on the left, standard one on the right).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Save a copy before loading `mathabx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\origpartial\partial
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$\origpartial\quad\partial$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can look into `fontmath.ltx` to see the original definition; with Bash it could be

```
less $(kpsewhich fontmath.ltx)
```

You'll find `\partial` on line 222. Copy the declaration into your document.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\partial}{\mathord}{letters}{"40} % fontmath.ltx, line 222

\begin{document}

$\partial f$

\end{document}
```

[image]